# Slick slider on('afterChange')

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I am trying to find option or method that gives me ability to change animation of active slider content before or after change. For example I have Slick slider called 'slider-header' and it has three `<h1>` tags inside like:

```
<div id="slider-header">
    <div>
        <h1>First header</h1>
        <h1>Second header</h1>
        <h1>Third header</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to slideOut(to left side) the first header with a little delay, then second header with the same delay, third header as well and only THEN I would like to change for next slide.
After change on the next slide, I would like those headers to appear in the same way but from the OTHER side.
I could reach only slide out to the left side with `setTimeout()` function and 'slickNext' method, but I have no idea how can I make them appear on the next slide from the other side in the same delay way.

Comment: show us your code. what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 7):

Slick slider has its own event called `afterChange`, and also as argument, it has `currentSlide` and `nextSlide` which you can use to make animations.

```
$('#slider-header > div').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    console.log(nextSlide);
});
```

Comment: Right, but next slide slides immediatly, and headers too.I would like them to appear one by one from the right side.Maybe I am using this event in the wrong way. Could you please make a jsfiddle to explain deeper? Thank you so much!

Comment: Use slick-current or slick-active class, when slide has slide-active class show the content with CSS effects. Otherwise hide the other elements until the slide ahs slide-active class.

Comment: I am trying to check if it hasClass, and nothing happens, is it possible to realize it with on('afterChange') event in some way? : if($("header-slide.slick-slide").hasClass('slick-current')) {
            alert("Has class!");
        }

Answer (score 2):

**I found the solution**.Using jQuery

```
prev()
```

or

```
next()
```

methods I can target direction of slider and which slide I need to animate.Thank you for help everybody!