# Script is no longer working if I filter the post archive

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a script it is working well. And when I filter the post archive the script no longer works. If I add the script on the post body the function is affecting the other post as well.

This is not the filter. This is the script that is being affected by Ajax. Added an update to the script but still does not work if the filter is activated

The function is working on this page on load
https://pna-manufacturing.staging.tempurl.host/projects/

I'm looking for a way to reload the script when the ajax is activated

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.grid-item-cont').each(function() {
        var $post = $(this);
        var $slickSlider = $post.find('.slick-slider');
        var $sliderTitle = $post.find('.slider-title');

        $slickSlider.on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
            if (currentSlide === 0) {               
                $sliderTitle.removeClass('overlay-slider');
            } else {
                $sliderTitle.addClass('overlay-slider');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: If you're replacing the HTML that contains .slick-slider then you'll need to reinitiated the event handler or use event delegation.   `afterChange` does not sound like a standard js event name.

Comment: @freedomn-m [the slickslider has its own events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41335722/slick-slider-onafterchange)

Comment: Your site is password protected

Comment: @mplungjan apart from the variable name `var $slickSlider` there's no reference to a third party plugin within the question.  (And we shouldn't be delving into linked sites).    Looks like a case of requiring event delegation.

Comment: 1. the slickSlider plugin HAS the afterChange event, so that is of course hard to ignore. 2. Yes it needs delegation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event handling is only working on load. You need to delegate so added posts will be treated

Something like this

```js
$(function() {
  const $container = $('#gridContainer').on('afterChange', '.grid-item-cont', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
    $this.find('.slider-title').toggleClass('overlay-slider', currentSlide !== 0)
  });
});
```

Comment: My Apologies I forgot the password protection

You can use this 

User: aj
pass:  cornmeal.skipping.tiny

Comment: I do not actually know what to do to see the issue, which you may already have solved based on my answer?

Comment: Your answer is acceptable. However, I tried this method before and causes a conflict with the slider scripts. 

The script I created was the only working one. but the only issue is when you activate the filter with Ajax the script no longer works or causes it to malfunction and you need to reload the page again in order to make it work.

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible to reload the script upon the filter activation.

Comment: It should work. You need to add the slider to each new post too in the ajax script